# while validating email form from jqueryvalidationlibrary it's blocking because it's integrated with database error message

Tags: javascript, html, forms, asp.net-core, validation

I am facing an issue while validating form field in client side in asp.net core validation message is not working and also some error message coming from database but If you I am doing validation in HTML CSS and javascript it's working fine.

Here, what I have done so far

```
<form class="ht_form" id="ht_form" action="" method="post">
                <div class="row ht_input-login">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div class="row mb-3 form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 ht_form-control form-label">
                                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control textbox-size"  value="@ValidEmail.Replace("@@", "@")"
                                       placeholder="Email ID" aria-describedby="emailError" autocomplete="off" required />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       
                        <div class="row ht_sign-in">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-6">
                                <button type="submit" class=" btn text-white w-100 mb-3 ">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                      
                       



                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
              @if (!IsvalidEmail)
                        {
                        
                                     <label class="row mb-3">
                                <p style="text-align:center;color:#a32035;margin-top:15px">
                                    Entered email id is not registered..
                                </p>
                            </label>
                                
                          
                        }
```

let me show validation done for this form

```js
$.validator.addMethod(
    "regex",
    function (value, element, regexp) {
        if (regexp && regexp.constructor != RegExp) {
            regexp = new RegExp(regexp);
        }
        else if (regexp.global) regexp.lastIndex = 0;
        return this.optional(element) || regexp.test(value);
    }, "Please enter a valid email like abc@gmail.com"
);

$().ready(function () {
    $("#ht_form").validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                regex: /^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\b$/i
            },
        },
        messages: {
            email: {
                required: "Please enter email address",
            },
        },
        errorElement: 'span',
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
            element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
        },


    });
});
```

Comment: client validation not working means when you input wrong email and click the submit button, It will not show any error message and still submit the form? What does `because it's integrated with database error message` mean? Are you using remote validation?

Comment: First I am validating code in html CSS and javascript through jquery validation it's working fine. But when I am integrating HTML code to asp.net code the validation is not working and in that form error message is also handling from backend like it's connected through database that showing your email id is not registered.

Comment: actually you can use default client validation in asp.net core instead of writing javascript by yourself, If you need, I can provide a simple demo.

Comment: and I have used jqueryvalidation library

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I think the `Email` property needs to be validated for the following three points: The value can't be null, The format fit email address and this email has not been registered, So you can create a model like:

```
public class MyEmail
    {
        //[RegularExpression("xxxxxx",ErrorMessage ="")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter email address")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email like abc@gmail.com")]
        [Remote(action: "ValidateEmail", controller: "Home")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

From above code, `[Remote(action: "ValidateEmail", controller: "Home")]` is a remote validation to validate if email has been registered.

Home controller ValidateEmail action:

```
public IActionResult ValidateEmail(string Email)
        {
            //mock check if email is  is already registered in the database
            List<string> emails = new List<string>();
            emails.Add("123456@gmail.com");
            emails.Add("654321@gmail.com");
            var result = emails.Where(x => x == Email).FirstOrDefault();

            if (result != null)
            {
                return Json(data: "This email is already been registered");
            }

            return Json(data: true);

        }
```

View

```
@model MyEmail


<form class="ht_form" id="ht_form" asp-action="privacy" method="post">
    <div class="row ht_input-login">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="row mb-3 form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12 ht_form-control form-label">
                    <input type="email" asp-for="Email" class="form-control textbox-size" 
                           placeholder="Email ID" aria-describedby="emailError" autocomplete="off" required />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row ht_sign-in">
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-6">
                    <button type="submit" class=" btn text-black w-100 mb-3 ">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    @section Scripts {
        @{
            await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");
        }
        }
</script>
```

Gif Demo

[image]

You can refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to learn more Built-in validation attributes.